# Preventing software keyboard from opening when clicking on an entry field in MAUI?

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit

Is there a way to prevent the software keyboard from opening when clicking on an entry field in MAUI?

Background: The entry field is only used to receive a barcode by a scan engine and to process it internally. A manual input should be avoided. Clicking on the field should only serve to set the focus, if not already done.

Comment: May I know on which platform do you want to prevent keyboard showing when the entry gets focused?

Comment: Just Android. For the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you can create a modified the mapper. See the offical docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize.

You can prevent the virtual keyboard from showing up when get focused on Android and place the modified mapper in `MauiProgram.cs` which will apply all `Entry` controls in your app.

Please refer to the sample code below:

```
public static class MauiProgram 
{
      public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
      {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                  });  
          Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("NoKeyboardEntry", (handler, entry) =>
            {
#if ANDROID
        handler.PlatformView.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
#endif
            });
        ;
```